# NLog disable specific logger - for real

Tags: nlog

NLog 4.6.6

I have tried everything to get a specific logger disabled and can't get it to work.  I'm wondering if it's a bug in NLog.  Based on [documentation](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#targets):

> There is one more level, Off. Since it is the highest value and is not used for entries, it disables logging when used as the minimum log level.

and:

> In case a rule is marked as final and contains any level-declaring attributes, the final attribute applies only to the specified levels.

So if I do the internet-recommended route (even [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972050/nlog-disable-a-specific-logger)), it still gets logged.

```
<logger name="Example.*" minlevel="Off" final="true" />
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" />
```

It is important for the answer to show the logger as disabled -- in order to short-circuit expensive debug code -- and not just dump it into the `Null` target.

Comment: Updated the wiki with example of how to create blackholes: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#blackhole

Comment: @RolfKristensen Thanks!  The existing documentation actually had all the information I needed to do it -- just needed to extrapolate.

Answer (score 4):

A little farther down on the documentation linked in the question in the examples, there is this:

> ```
> <logger name="Name.Space.*" minlevel="Debug" maxlevel="Error" final="true" />
> <logger name="*" writeTo="f1" />
> ```
>
> Configures to ignore messages from any class in the Name.Space
> namespace with level between Debug and Error (which is Debug, Info,
> Warn, Error). The first rule selects loggers, but since there is no
> writeTo, these messages are not logged. And, since this rule contains
> 'final=true', the last rule does not apply to loggers matching the
> first rule.

I tried the following and it worked:

```
<logger name="Example.*" minlevel="Trace" final="true" />
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" />
```

The key was to just specify the lowest level (`Trace`) as `minlevel`, not `Off`.  And that matches the rules of what the documentation says.

I'm guessing this has changed over the versions and hence the confusion.

Comment: Yes NLog 4.0 changed the behavior of `final="true"`, if you find wiki-pages on the NLog-project that contains wrong info then please tell. See also https://nlog-project.org/2015/06/09/nlog-4-has-been-released.html

Comment: @RolfKristensen Thanks, I will keep that in mind in the future.