# Unable to reduce verbosity of specific loggers in NLog

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

I upgraded from NLog 4. to NLog v5 a couple of days ago in an ASP.Net / .Net 6 environment. As soon as I updated I noticed that I was getting details from many more loggers than I had in the past (I still haven't figure out why).

To reduce the chattiness, I began creating rules in my NLog.config to remove the noise. I used both the NLog documentation as well as this SO question as my guide: [NLog disable specific logger - for real](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66337872/nlog-disable-specific-logger-for-real).

Unfortunately, the rules seem to be ignored. I'm still getting lots and lots of Info level logging from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.*`

Am I missing something simple here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Info"
      internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog.txt">

  <!-- Ensure all times are logged in UTC -->
  <time type="AccurateUTC" />

  <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
    <add assembly="NLog.Database"/>
  </extensions>

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    <target name="db"
            xsi:type="Database"
            commandType="StoredProcedure"
            commandText="[dbo].[NLog_AddEntry_p]"
            connectionString="${configsetting:item=ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection}">
      <parameter name="@errorId" layout="${mdlc:item=errorId}" />
      <parameter name="@ipAddress" layout="${aspnet-request-ip}" />
      <parameter name="@machineName" layout="${machinename}" />
      <parameter name="@siteName" layout="${iis-site-name}" />
      <parameter name="@logged" layout="${date}" />
      <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
      <parameter name="@username" layout="${aspnet-user-identity}" />
      <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />
      <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />
      <parameter name="@properties" layout="${all-event-properties:separator=|}" />
      <parameter name="@serverName" layout="${aspnet-Request-Host}" />
      <parameter name="@serverAddress" layout="${aspnet-request-url}" />
      <parameter name="@callSite" layout="${callsite}" />

      <parameter name="@requestMethod" layout="${aspnet-request-method}" />
      <parameter name="@payload" layout="${aspnet-request-posted-body}" />
      <parameter name="@queryString" layout="${aspnet-request-querystring}" />
      <parameter name="@referrer" layout="${aspnet-request-referrer}" />
      <parameter name="@userAgent" layout="${aspnet-request-useragent}" />
        
      <!--<parameter name="@exception" layout="${exception:tostring}:${stacktrace:format=Enum:topFrames=Integer:skipFrames=Integer:separator=String}" />-->
      <parameter name="@exception" layout="${exception:format=ToString,StackTrace:format=ToString}${newline}" />
    </target>
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
      <!--Disable logging of specific overly talkative loggers-->
      <logger name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.*" minlevel="Warning" final="true" />
      <logger name="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.*" minlevel="Warning" final="true" />
      <!--END Disable logging of specific overly talkative loggers-->

      <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="db" />
      <logger name="*" minLevel="Fatal" writeTo="mail" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are hit by this breaking change [NLog.Extensions.Logging without any filter](https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html#nlogextensionslogging-without-any-filter) in NLog 5.0.

The recommend solution is to update your NLog.config to perform the filtering. It can be done like this using `maxLevel=""`:

```xml
  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
      <logger name="Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime" minLevel="Info" writeTo="db" />
      <!--Disable logging of specific overly talkative loggers-->
      <logger name="Microsoft*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />
      <!--END Disable logging of specific overly talkative loggers-->

      <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="db" />
      <logger name="*" minLevel="Fatal" writeTo="mail" />
  </rules>
```

NLog 5.0 also introduces support for [finalMinLevel](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-Rules-FinalMinLevel):

```xml
  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
      <!--Disable logging of specific overly talkative loggers-->
      <logger name="Microsoft*" finalMinLevel="Warn" />
      <logger name="Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime" finalMinLevel="Info" />
      <!--END Disable logging of specific overly talkative loggers-->

      <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="db" />
      <logger name="*" minLevel="Fatal" writeTo="mail" />
  </rules>
```

Notice `finalMinLevel=""` is similar to Microsoft Logging Filter Configuration, where it is easier to override the default-filter like for `"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime"`.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that in the documentation. Thanks!